# J5 - Utilising com_fields in component

Tags: custom-component, joomla-5.x, com-fields

I'm lost with utilising com_fields in my component so that my users can create a custom field for a specific purpose and have it rendered in a modal popup.

So I have my component setup with a dashboard and the option for admins to create custom fields and groups, this all works fine and dandy.  In the admin side edit.php of an item I can actually see a list of custom fields available that have been created and select one from the list as a reference to the specific item.  Now I wish to display/render the chosen field in my modal popup.  I assumed I should be able to use the following to render the field like this:

```
    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('id'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('field_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->form->renderField('user_id'); ?>
    <?php if ($this->item->field_id) : ?>
        <?php $fields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_mycomponent.recordform', $this->item, true); ?>
        <?php echo $this->form->renderField($fields[0]->name); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

My tmpl file is called modalrec.php and the model being used is recordform.php.  I've seen mention of needing to have a plugin to trigger an event which I don't understand.  Surely if I have the fields setup (in this case a radio field with 3 options) I can simply get the field and show the options available.  But alas I can't see it.  Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I have it although if anyone else can suggest a better way, please do.  So basically I have create xml entry for the field and have an empty fieldset/group in the form xml proper.

```
        <?php if ($this->item->field_id) : ?>
            <?php $fields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_mycomponent.motionform', $this->item->field_id, true); ?>
            <?php 
                $options = '';
                foreach ($fields as $fld) {
                    if ($fld->id == $this->item->field_id) {
                        $opts = ArrayHelper::fromObject($fld->fieldparams->get('options'));
                        $fldParams = json_decode($fld->params);
                        foreach ($opts as $opt) {
                            $options .= '<option value="'.$opt['value'].'">'.Text::_($opt['name']).'</option>';
                        }
                        $xmlFld = new SimpleXMLElement(
                            '<field name="'.$fld->name.'" type="'.$fld->type.'" class="'.$fldParams->class.'" label="" description="" >'.$options.'</field>'
                        );
                        $this->form->setField($xmlFld,'custfldmotions',true,'custflds');
                    }
                }
            ?>
            <?php echo $this->form->renderFieldset('custflds'); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

And in the form xml we have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 . . . .
<fieldset name="custflds">
    <fields name="custfldmotions">
    </fields>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Tweeked the options collection for only the field I was interested in.